# Is there a way to "recall" a char sequence already matched in the regex itself?

Tags: regex, delimiter

The regex I'm searching has the following constraints:

- it starts with "//"
- then "[" a non number sequence (called delimiter in this list) and "]"
- next line "\n"
- "[" 0 or more number separated by the delimiter previously found "]".

For example the following text matches the regex:

```
//[*#*]
[1*#*34*#*64]
```

and the following text doesn't match the regex:

```
//[*#*]
[1#34#64]
```

because the delimiter is not the same matched in the first row

The regex I currently create is

```
^//\[(\D)+\]\n\[[(\d)+(\D)+]*(\d)+\]$|^//\[(\D)+\]\n\[\]$|^//\[(\D)+\]\n\[(\d)+\]$
```

but obviously this regex match with both previous examples.

Is there a way to "recall" a char sequence already matched in the regex itself?

Comment: Look up _back-references_. For a quick example `\(.*\)\1` matches any string of the form `<s><s>`. Meaning, a string made of concatenating a string to itself.

Comment: What is the language you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something called back-reference (a very good tutorial [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)).

Use this regex in Python:

```python
r'^//\[([^\]]+)\]\n\[\d+(\1\d+)*\]'
```

Sample run:

```python
>>> string = """//[*#*]
... [1*#*34*#*64]"""
>>> print re.search(r'^//\[([^\]]+)\]\n\[\d+(\1\d+)*\]',string).group(0)
//[*#*]
[1*#*34*#*64]
```

will match your string in Python.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2gu5SaYVwaFGiAVi)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a back-reference, in most languages you can reference a matching group using `\n` where `n` is the group number.

This pattern will work:

```
//\[([^]]++)]\n\[(?>\d++\1?)+]
```

To break it down:

- `//` just matches the literal
- `\[([^]]++)]` matches some characters in square brackets
- `\n` matches the newline
- `\[(?:\d++\1?)++]` matches one or more digits followed by the match captured in the first pattern section - optionally. This is an atomic group.